# Nginx dynamic configuration

Tags: web-services, nginx, service-discovery

I have a couple of questions:

**I. Is it possible to configure nginx after startup?**

Example scenario:

1. Daemon started only with knowledge of settings like HTTP url or Consul addr.
2. Nginx fetches settings from the address provided.
3. Nginx reload/restart and apply them.
4. Nginx could reload cfg by SIGNAL.

**II. Is it possible to force nginx to make a decision about which upstream HTTP request needs to be sent based on HTTP subrequest?**

Like there 3rd party service which could make a decision based on the cookie.
 Ngx send cookie to the service, it replies with upstream addr?

Comment: Errors detected in post: (1) Multiple questions being asked -> CloseVoteReason: Too Broad; (2) Not a programming question -> CloseVoteReason: Offtopic.  (You should really be asking these questions on a different site that *isn't* Programming related because this isn't a programming question)